# How to know if a Recurly subscription will renew at the end of its period?

Tags: recurly

When viewing an active, non-renewing subscription on the Recurly website, such as

```
https://xxxxxx.recurly.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxba354d5b84812419xxxxxxxx
```

the Recurly website shows info like this:

> Status: Active
>   Start Date: Feb 9, 2016 7:44 PM UTC
>   Current Period: Feb 09, 2016 — Mar 09, 2016
>   Next Invoice: **Will not renew**
>   Billing Cycles: **0 renewals remaining (of 1)**
>   End Date: Mar 9, 2016 7:44 PM UTC

Looking up the same subscription using the Recurly API, I cannot figure out how to determine if the subscription will renew. This is PHP, but language doesn't matter:

```
const TFORMAT = "D d M H:i:s \U\T\C Y";
$sub = Recurly_Subscription::get('xxxxxxxxba354d5b84812419xxxxxxxx');
echo $sub->state;
echo '<br>' . ($sub->activated_at ? $sub->activated_at->format(TFORMAT) : "nope");
echo '<br>' . ($sub->current_period_started_at ? $sub->current_period_started_at->format(TFORMAT) : "nope");
echo '<br>' . ($sub->current_period_ends_at ? $sub->current_period_ends_at->format(TFORMAT) : "nope");
echo '<br>' . ($sub->expires_at ? $sub->expires_at->format(TFORMAT) : "nope");
echo '<br>' . ($sub->canceled_at ? $sub->canceled_at->format(TFORMAT) : "nope");
```

This outputs:

> active
>   Tue 09 Feb 19:44:48 UTC 2016
>   Tue 09 Feb 19:44:48 UTC 2016
>   Wed 09 Mar 19:44:48 UTC 2016
>   nope
>   nope

How can I determine if this subscription will renew?

Answer (score 2):

Sent my request to Recurly Support and got this reply. Hope it helps someone in the future:

> A subscription that has a fixed
>   number of billing cycles does not renew. A subscription details API
>   call of this type of subscription would expose the following
>   parameters:
>
> - `total_billing_cycles`
> - `remaining_billing_cycles`
>
> These parameters are not exposed with a renewable subscription.
>
> Therefore by adding (PHP) these lines in the details call will ID
>   whether the subscription is a non-renewing subscription:
>
> // test to determine if the total_billing_cycles parameter is
>   exposed/present
>
> ```
>   if (isset($subscription->total_billing_cycles)) {
>     // If true...do something
>     echo "This subscription will not renew";
>   }
> ```
>
> I hope this answers your question.  Thank you again. Regards,
>
> Ian Recurly Support

Answer (score 0):

I never used Recurly but it seems like you first have to get the invoice of the subscription.

When you have the invoice, you could use the

```
<state>open</state>
```

and

```
<collection_method>automatic</collection_method>
```

to calculate, if the subscription will be renewed.

Comment: No. That is invoice-specific. There can be many invoices per subscription. A particular invoice could have been collected at a time when the subscription was recurring, while at present it may no longer be recurring.